# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-modsecurity

Tags: apache2, dpkg

I am facing this problem when installing modsecurity for apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit xenial

```
root@mytestmachine:~# apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-security2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-security2 is already the newest version (2.9.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-mod-security2 (2.9.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-security2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-modsecurity:
 libapache2-modsecurity depends on libapache2-mod-security2; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-security2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-modsecurity (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of modsecurity-crs:
 modsecurity-crs depends on libapache2-mod-security2 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package libapache2-mod-security2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package modsecurity-crs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-security2
 libapache2-modsecurity
 modsecurity-crs
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any pointers will be greatly helpful because I am not too experienced with Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Did you try with `apt install -f`? It looks seem something happened during the installation, and it is not finished.

Comment: Thanks spas - so I'd just do a "apt install -f"   or does it go with any other switches?

Comment: Just `apt -f install`. It means `--fix-broken`.

Comment: Done that and the same error still :(